# Characters conversions between Windows and OSX

Tags: windows, macos, matlab, character-encoding

### Premise

I was not able to give a proper title to the question, please help if you can improve it. I would also like some help with tags.

### Question

I'm in MATLAB (Win 8.1) trying to read files from another hard disk, which is a HFS+ drive with OSX.

```
for k = 1:10000 //%lot of files
    load(['D:\Users\user\Desktop\mats\Some file à',num2str(k),'.mat'])
end
```

Console says that files are not really there, but I know they are. After some time I got the problem resides in the `à` charachter, that is present in every single filename.

If I go:

```
cd('D:\Users\user\Desktop\mats\');
ls
```

I see that the **à** character is seen by Windows as a simple `a` followed by a backtick, **a`**. However, if I call

```
load('D:\...\Some file a`.mat)
```

It doesn't work either. Is there something I can to to bypass this problem? I can't load and rename each file because, well, I can't read them. And I would avoid logging into the OSX drive, since it does not belong to me and would bring non-programming, but annoying, issues.

Any ideas, or notions about how characters are converted from OS to OS?

### Edit

I add that I know files are there because there is `One lucky file.mat` that has no `à` whatsoever, and I can easily load it. With help from @horchler in comments I verified that, for `à` files, MATLAB refuses the filenames it just listed out, which looks totally weird to me.

Comment: It isn't a general solution, but it should be possible to figure out what character(s) are causing this issue (or at least what they are represented as on Windows). In Matlab: `files=dir('D:\Users\user\Desktop\mats\');` `files.names`. Find the index of one of the problem files, say 10, then `file_str=files(10).name`. Then you can use `double(file_str)` to veie the char codes for each character.

Comment: The original Mac file names are Unicode. I don't know and can't test what Windows and/or Matlab may do to them when they read them. Another thing you might try is something like `unicode2native(filename, 'US-ASCII')`.

Comment: Also, what do `feature('DefaultCharacterSet')` and `get_param(0, 'CharacterEncoding')` return?

Comment: @horchler I tried `dir()` but I can't get anything out of it, because even calling `load(file_str)` fails. That's totally weird. As for your last comment, they both return `windows-1252`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `load`. `dir` is nothing more than a more complicated version of `ls`, which appears to works for you. You could try the same with `ls` if you prefer, but note that it will pad the output with extra spaces. It may also modify the character differently than `dir`.

Comment: @horchler these are workspaces that I need to load to fetch data. And `ls` is not working either: in both cases I ask MATLAB *what's in this dir*, it gives me filenames (a bit different from the original ones, because à is split into two chars), and when I ask it to load one of those it says *no such file*. Plus (see edited question) I know that `load`ing from this drive is possible, because I have a single mat file with no à in it, that I can easily load.

Comment: Many cross-platform applications simply can't handle Unicode filenames on Windows.  MATLAB might be one of them, in which case the only option is to rename the files.  (It might also be an issue with the PC<->Mac communication; try copying the files to your local disk and see if it can read them then.)

Comment: @Harry copying manually the files to the Win drive didn't help. Also tried `R` but it failed the same way. I will end up renaming since there's nothing I can do. Thanks.